# Pop the current page after a futureProvider in flutter using riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, riverpod

I want to pop the current screen after a completed future , the future itself provided by futureProvider in riverpod. I used result.when and navigate back but the it doesn't work.

I have a futureProvider that return a object :

```dart
final addContentFutureProvider =
    FutureProvider.family<ContentCollection?, AddContentParams>(
        (ref, params) => ref.watch(databaseHelperProvider).addContent(params));
```

I want to pop the current page after this future, I test it in this way but i doesn't work :

```dart
                    ref
                        .read(addContentFutureProvider(
                          AddContentParams(
                            languageCode: languageDropDownValue,
                            title: titleController.text,
                            mainContent: contentController.text,
                            source: urlController.text,
                          ),
                        ))
                        .when(
                          data: (data) {
                            context.pop(data);
                          },
                          error: (error, stackTrace) {},
                          loading: () {},
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ref.watch` in the `build` method:

```
ref.watch(addContentFutureProvider(...)).when(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I want to call the future when user tap on the button, so if I watch the futureProvider on the build method, is there any way to call it in the onPressed of the button ?

Comment: yes, then you need to use `ref.read`. Also, it will be convenient to use the `whenOrNull` or `maybeWhen` method. It might be worth considering `AsyncNotifier` for more convenient state management.